# How to include and use ui-router in my app without injector errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angularjs-injector

UPDATE I've reverted back to a state before including any ui-router

---

I was getting that terrible $injector error that I could not solve, I've since reverted back and need to know how to simply include ui-router and add in a Config function that will simply route the user to /login which loads /login.html

I've done this many times before, just this time it won't work.

```
(function() { "use strict";

    var app = angular.module('tickertags', [
        'infinite-scroll',
        'apiFactory',
        'scopeFactory',
        'tagFactory',
        'tickerFactory',
        'timeSpanFactory',
        'overlayDirective',
        'searchPopoverDirectives',
        'notificationDirectives',
        'platformHeaderDirectives',
        'controlHeaderDirectives',
        'viewHeaderDirectives',
        'alertsPanelController',
        'alertPanelDirectives',
        'tickersPanelDirectives',
        'tickersSelectFactory',
        'tagsPanelDirectives',
        'tagDetailsFactory',
        'tagHoverDirective',
        'tagSearchDirective',
        'tagsFilterDirective',
        'focusMeDirective',
        'chartHeaderController',
        'chartHeaderDirectives',
        'chartPanelDirective',
        'chartIQDirective',
        'socialMediaController',
        'socialMediaDirectives',
        'socialMediaFactory'
    ])
    .controller('DashCtrl', Controller);

    /*
        I WANT TO ADD THE CONFIG HERE...
        /login = login.html
    */

    Controller.$inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$rootScope',
        'ScopeFactory',
        'TickerFactory'];

    function Controller($scope,
                        $rootScope,
                        ScopeFactory,
                        TickerFactory) {

        /** Init DashCtrl scope */
        /** ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
        var vs          = $scope;
            vs.showNote = true,
            vs.mouseX   = '',
            vs.mouseY   = '';
            ScopeFactory.saveScope('root', vs);

        /** Detect if a tagHover has been shown and ready bodyClick to close */
        vs.$on('tagHoverOpen', function(events,data) {
            vs.bodyClick = function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('bodyClick');
            };
        });

        /** Remove eventListener after tagHover is closed */
        vs.$on('destroy', function() {
            vs.bodyClick = angular.noop();
        });

        /** Get and store all tickers, eventually just first 100 */
        getAllTickers();

        function getAllTickers() {
            TickerFactory.getTickers();
        };

    };

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ui.router` module inside your app module to use angular `ui.router` features.

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('tickertags', [
    //..other modules here.
    'socialMediaFactory',
    'ui.router' //<--added it
])
```

Comment: Ah I thought that was it... just added it though, but still getting the same error :( I think maybe it's the way my Controller is setup in the app.js

Comment: No there is no any issue with your controller declaration..could you do hard refresh & check angular-ui-router.js loaded or not

Comment: This is NUTS I completely remove the config function, and I'm still getting an error saying I'm missing `ngRoute`???

Comment: you must have been added `ng-view` instead of that you should add `ui-view` could you add your html?

Comment: sure, will add that to my question but also here index: https://gist.github.com/leongaban/aebb3dfa02abc6ffc8ac app.js https://gist.github.com/leongaban/5e187a0c5b7159d18282

Comment: LoginController is not included (line 127). That's also what your error message says: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=loginController

Comment: you code looks cool..but by commenting dashboard controller code nothing will work..& i didn't saw ui-view in your html to kick off the angular-ui-router

Comment: do you have $route or $routeProvider dependancy anywhere in you app controller or service.??

Comment: @pankajparkar no where at all... this is seriously insane... I'm going to revert my app.js and back track to where there is no errors

Comment: Ok just reverted my code back to a working state, how would you add in ui-router here? And the config function?

Comment: 1st add ui-router.js then add ui.router in you app model..write `ui-view` directive..then add various states inside your config block that will have various state with different templates and controllers

Comment: Ok I did that, but it gives me the ngRoute error?  I'm using Angular 1.3.15 think maybe I need to upgrade to 1.4 and use the new router there?

Comment: 1.4 added more problems than I was willing to solve. @pankajparkar the actual problem was, embarrassingly that I needed to have angular.js above my ui-router script link :( fail... and +1 for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79076/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-leon-gaban).

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the framework for your project using yeoman (which is always a good idea to bootstrap your project and avoid writing lot of boilerplate code), then you would have an existing bower and grunt configuration in your project.

From there on, these are the steps you can follow for replacing ngRouter in your project with ui-router

1. Execute `bower install angular-ui-router --save`
2. Modify your index.html by replacing

`<div ng-view=""></div> with <div ui-view=""></div>`

3. Update your app.js to include the ui-router module and the appropriate configuration for different states

Here's a sample configuration:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, send to /
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
      .state('/', {
        url:"/",
        templateUrl: '../modules/main/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url:"/about",
        templateUrl: '../modules/about/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
      });
  });
```

If you have grunt and bower configured for your project then the dependent `angular-ui-router.js` will be added automatically to your index.html

Comment: The thing with Yeoman though is it usually adds a ton of stuff I don't need and never use :( it's a great tool tho, for fast small projects. If I keep using the same build I'm using now, Angular + Gulp and my own `sass-smacss` bower package, I may 1 day upload my own Yeoman :)